# Search for substring and store another part of the string as variable in perl

Tags: regex, perl, substring

I am revamping an old mail tool and adding MIME support. I have a lot of it working but I'm a perl dummy and the regex stuff is losing me.

I had:

```
foreach ( @{$body} ) {

   next if /^$/;

   if ( /NEMS/i ) {
      /.*?(\d{5,7}).*/;
      $nems = $1;
      next;
   }

   if ( $delimit ) {
      next if (/$delimit/ && ! $tp);
      last if (/$delimit/ && $tp);

      $tp = 1, next if /text.plain/;
      $tp = 0, next if /text.html/;
      s/<[^>]*>//g;
      $newbody .= $_ if $tp;
   } else {
      s/<[^>]*>//g;
      $newbody .= $_ ;
   }
}  # End Foreach
```

Now I have `$body_text` as the plain text mail body thanks to [MIME::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MIME-tools/lib/MIME/Parser.pm). So now I just need this part to work:

```
foreach ( @{$body_text} ) {

   next if /^$/;

   if ( /NEMS/i ) {
      /.*?(\d{5,7}).*/;
      $nems = $1;
      next;
   }
}  # End Foreach
```

The actual challenge is to find `NEMS=12345` or `NEMS=1234567` and set `$nems=12345` if found. I think I have a very basic syntax problem with the test because I'm not exposed to perl very often.

A coworker suggested:

```
foreach (split(/\n/,$body_text)){

    next if /^$/;

    if ( /NEMS/i ) {
        /.*?(\d{5,7}).*/;

        $nems = $1;
next;

    }
}
```

Which seems to be working, but it may not be the preferred way?

edit:

So this is the most current version based on tips here and testing:

```
foreach (split(/\n/,$body_text)){

    next if /^$/;

    if ( /NEMS/i ) {
        /^\s*NEMS\s*=\s*(\d+)/i;

        $nems = $1;
    next;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can there be yet another digit following -- can there be eight digits?  Or is what may follow strictly non-digit?

Comment: As for "_A coworker suggested_" -- if `$body_text` a plain string their suggestion is correct, but if it is a reference to an array ("_arrayref_") the original should be used.  These are very different.

Comment: The "old" code that used the old Mail perl module was an array. In the new MIME one it's not an array.  --Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Match the last two digits as optional and capture the first five, and assign the capture directly

```
($nems) = /(\d{5}) (?: \d{2} )?/x;  # /x allows spaces inside
```

The construct `(?: )` only groups what's inside, without capture. The `?` after it means to match that zero or one time. We need parens so that it applies to that subpattern only. So the last two digits are optional -- five digits or seven digits match. I removed the unneeded `.*?` and `.*`

However, by what you say it appears that the whole thing can be simplified

```
if ( ($nems) = /^\s*NEMS \s* = \s* (\d{5}) (?:\d{2})?/ix ) { next }
```

where there is now no need for `if (/NEMS/)` and I've adjusted to the clarification that `NEMS` is at the beginning and that there may be spaces around `=`.  Then you can also say

```
my $nems;

foreach ( split /\n/, $body_text ) {
    # ...
    next if ($nems) = /^\s*NEMS\s*=\s*(\d{5})(?:\d{2})?/i;
    # ...
}
```

what includes the clarification that the new `$body_text` is a multiline string.

It is clear that `$nems` is declared (needed) *outside* of the loop and I indicate that.

This allows yet more digits to follow; it will match on 8 digits as well (but capture only the first five). This is what your trailing `.*` in the regex implies.

**Edit**   It's been clarified that there can only be 5 or 7 digits.  Then the regex can be tightened, to check whether input is as expected, but it should work as it stands, too.

---

A few notes, let me know if more would be helpful

- The match operator returns a list so we *need* the parens in `($nems) = /.../;`
- The `($nems) = /.../` syntax is a nice shortcut, for `($nems) = $_ =~ /.../;`.
  If you are matching on a variable other than `$_` then you need the whole thing.
- You *always* want to start Perl programs with

  ```
  use warnings 'all';
  use strict;
  ```

  This directly helps and generally results in better code.

---

The clarification of the evolved problem understanding states that all digits following `=` need be captured into `$nems` (and there may be 5,(not 6),7,8,9,10 digits).  Then the regex is simply

```
($nems) = /^\s*NEMS\s*=\s*(\d+)/i;
```

where `\d+` means a digit, one or more times. So a string of digits (match fails if there are none).

Comment: @MarkM  I misunderstood a part of the question at first. Adjusted the answer to what I think you need.

Comment: I added a coworker suggestion to the question. Comments welcome. The original assumption was that asset ID tags are always either 5 digits or 7. We specified that email request bodies could have the asset ID to help assign the ticket to the right asset. NEMS=xxxxx, or NEMS = xxxxx are two possible patterns, and NEMS will always be at the beginning of the line with nothing else in the line. $nems is used later to look up the asset in the database.

Comment: @MarkM  I've updated to these clarifications.  These are "normal" regex tweaks, sorry I didn't put in all spaces etc.  As for the coworker's suggestion, see my comment below the question: that would indicate that `$body_text` is just a multi-line string, what is very different from what you say you processed successfully for `$body`(being an arrayref).  You can see by `print "$body_text\n"` -- if it prints `ARRAY(...)` then the original version is right (`@$body_text`), if it prints the whole thing then change to the new one. This would only chage the `foreach` line.

Comment: Yep, thanks, it's not an array in the new code. That initially threw me for a loop. That was programming humor ;-)  Really bad programming humor. ;-)

Comment: Damn, I just looked, and the NEMS can now be 5,7,8,9 or 10 digits :-O

Comment: @MarkM No, that _was_ funny :).  So by 5 - 10 digits do you mean that the string may have that many but you still need 5?  Or ... ?  (Also, you skipped "6" in the list -- on purpose?)  The code as it stands will accept 5, or 7, or anything more, and it captures the first five.

Comment: @MarkM Updated for `$body_text` being a multi-line string, not an arrayref.

Comment: The possible NEMS number lengths are as listed above, and the $nems captured variable must be the complete string for the SQL lookup to work. None of the numbers are 6 digits long (weird). BTW, I believe as it stands I have just one issue that kills it if I use "use strict;". I need to report back about that next week.

Comment: @MarkM Alright, let's clear this up.  I thought, by the question, that you want to find the string for `NEMS` with either 5 or 7 digits, but that you want to take only the first five into `$nems`.  Are you saying that all digits should go into `$nems`?  (And there happen to be only 5,7,8,9,10, no 6.)  If that's the case, that is easy

Comment: @MarkM OK.  One more question then: what are other possible constraints?  What if there happen to be 11 digits, is that still OK (should `$nems` then get all 11 -- or not -- or should the script yell of errors in data)?

Comment: @MarkM  I added in the end the regex that takes all digits that follow `NEMS=` (spaces or no spaces around `=`).  If no digits follow the whole match fails.  I kept the rest intact to match the question as it stands.  Just change the regex.  Let me know of any other updates in requirements.

Comment: Awesome, there is really no reason for a sanity check here. There are checks obviously when the ID is entered in the database. This is simply a way to auto-assign a new ticket to the correct computer(person). If NEMS fails it falls back on a lookup based on the user name, then guesses about the computer ID if they have multiple.